# how do i boot up into ubuntu on an acer aspire v5 froma flash drive/disk?

Tags: boot

I plug in the USB with Ubuntu on it and i press f12 and i click USB but it just goes into normal windows. And after trying multiple times it still dosent work need help?

Answer (score 1):

When you first boot the pc, there should be some sort of notice on the screen which might say press F12 to boot to alternate media.  If it says F12 then you are using the correct key.  If it is not working the problem could be that your flash drive wasn't written properly.  To test it, try booting a different, preferably older PC.  If it works on other PCs but not this one it could be that the v5 employs an EFI bios which is problematic for ubuntu boot media but not completely impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just having trouble getting the PC to boot from the USB, or if the Ubuntu USB wasn't created successfully, this help page has instructions that should help with eiter case: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Specifically the sections:

> ### [Booting the Computer from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB)
>
> Remove all unneeded USB items, but keep the network cable attached.
>
> Insert the bootable USB flash drive that you just created in your
>   target computer and restart it. Most newer computers can boot from a
>   USB flash drive. If your computer does not automatically do so, you
>   might need to edit the BIOS settings.
>
> Restart your computer, and watch for a message telling you which key
>   to press to enter the BIOS setup. It will usually be one of F1, F2,
>   DEL, ESC or F10. Press this key while your computer is booting to edit
>   your BIOS settings. (On HP Mini Netbooks, they correct key is usually
>   F9.)
>
> Instead of editing BIOS settings, you can chose a boot device from the
>   boot menu. Press the function key to enter the boot menu when your
>   computer is booting. Typically, the boot screen displays which key you
>   need to press. It maybe one of F12, F10. Note: with some motherboards
>   you have to select 'hard disk/USB-HDD0' to choose the USB flash disk.
>   It may work like this because the system sees the USB drive 'a mass
>   storage device' as a hard disk drive, and it should be at the top of
>   the boot order list.
>
> So you need to edit the Boot Order. Depending on your computer, and
>   how your USB key was formatted, you should see an entry for "removable
>   drive" or "USB media". Move this to the top of the list to make the
>   computer attempt to boot from the USB device before booting from the
>   hard disk.

Or maybe it's trouble with [**Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive** from Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows), where you can use these (there's info on creating from other OS's on the page too):

- PenDriveLinux's [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) [Not listed on the help page but very good]
- [Linux Live Usb Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)
- [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager)

Or you may have [**UEFI**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#UEFI) **troubles**

> ### UEFI
>
> There is a good wiki page about [booting with UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), and a good tutorial
>   thread, [UEFI Installing - Tips](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295).
>
> If you want to boot in UEFI mode and install your Ubuntu flavour
>   alongside Windows, you should use a 64-bit ISO file, for example
>
> `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`
>
> directly and not via grub2.
>
> ### Creating an EFI-only image
>
> If you need to install Ubuntu in EFI-only mode, you might want to
>   create a EFI only image. [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/) describes how to do this.